# If you don't declare a MIME type for css file, does the server attempt to determine it?

Tags: html, apache, http-headers

I was observing my HTTP headers for css files and noticed both stylesheets

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stuff1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stuff2.css">
```

had the following `Content-Type: text/css` in their HTTP headers.  Is it the server that is guessing the `Content-Type`?

Also - what is the purpose of declaring the mime type in the `<link>` tag if the server is going to determine what the mime type is anyways?

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so the `type` attribute is required for a `<link>` tag. The HTML 4.01/HTML 5 specs state it to be an "advisory" hint as to the content type of the content available at the link target address.

The [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/semantics.html#attr-link-type) says -

**If the attribute is omitted, but the external resource link type has a default type defined, then the user agent must assume that the resource is of that type.**

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP server sets the Content-Type dependent on a list of mimetypes it has stored.

You don't have to specify it in the link tag, but I imagine it means the server doesn't have to guess, plus it means you can have a `css.min` file with `type="text/css"` and it still be served as css